# Getting Error "parsererror" "Error: jQuery21106393266040831804_1456914722748 was not called" On Ajax Call Reactjs

Tags: ajax, reactjs

Here I wrote A code which fetches data from API http://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent and displays on console for starter but I'm Getting Error Like "parsererror" "Error: jQuery21106393266040831804_1456914722748 was not called"

```js
var App = React.createClass({
    //setting up initial state
    getInitialState:function(){
        return{
            data:[]
        };
    },
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getDataFromServer('http://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent');
    },
    //showResult Method
    showResult:function(response){
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            data:response.results
        });
    },
    //making ajax call to get data from server
    getDataFromServer:function(URL){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"jsonp",
            url:URL,
            success: function(response) {
                this.showResult(response);
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Result />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var Result = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <ResultItem/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var ResultItem = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <li>Hello This Is From ResultItem Component</li>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="demo.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `API` returns `JSON`, you don't need use `JSONP`, just change `dataType` from `jsonp` to `json`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  ....
});
```

and in `showResult` set only `response` because `response` contains `Array` of `Objects` and does not have `results` property

```
this.setState({
  data: response
});
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/33247/)